# How to install WaveShare 4-inch LCD in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, display

I tried to get the 4 inch display working with my raspberry pi 3 (Waveshare Raspberry Pi 4 Inch Touch Screen TFT LCD(A) 320*480 for Raspberry Pi RPi Model B/Raspberry Pi 2 Model B/Raspberry Pi 3 Model B).

I always had a white screen until I found "Bim"s solution in this question ([How to install Waveshare SpotPear 4 inch LCD in RaspberryPI 2?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27714/how-to-install-waveshare-spotpear-4-inch-lcd-in-raspberrypi-2)). I followed his answer step for step and it changed the color of the display to black.

What I know now:

- the driver is already part of the raspbian kernel so I don't have to install it
- I have to copy the waveshare overlay for the 4 inch display from https://github.com/swkim01/waveshare-dtoverlays (I used the overlay for linux kernel > 4.4) to /boot/overlays/
- modify the /boot/config.txt by adding dtoverlay=waveshare35a,speed=14000000

someone another idea what I have to do to get this display working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after hours of searching I found this tutorial that works like a charm!

http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/

But CAUTION! skip step 3!
You don't have to install rpi-firmware from https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware when you use a linux kernel > 4.4.
If you do that you will cause a kernel panic. Then you have to reinstall raspbian again.

The only problem that appears is missing touch callibration, maybe this is caused by the tutorial maybe not. If I can find a solution for that I will post it here.